# How to use browserhistory.push() if the Router and the Firebase authentication are in two different classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication and it's working.

Code App.js:

```
  addUser(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(event.target.correo.value, event.target.clave.value).catch(function(error) {
    ban=false;
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {

            alert('Wrong password.');
        }

    else if(errorCode=='auth/email-already-in-use'){
      alert("esa cuenta de correo ya esta en uso");
    }
    else {
            alert(errorMessage);
          }
          console.log(error);
        });
  }


  ingresar(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(event.target.email.value,event.target.pass.value).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {

              alert('contraseña incorrecta');
          }
      else if(errorCode==='auth/user-not-found'){
            alert('Usuario inexistente');
      }
          else {
                  alert(errorMessage);
                }
                console.log(error);

});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if(user){
    browserHistory.push('/Nosotros');
  } else {

  }
  });
}
```

If the login is successful, I then use `browserHistory.push` to redirect to other components in other class, but the Router is in a Different class
than App.js and the component class.

Code Index.js

```
class AppStart extends React.Component{

render(){
  return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="/Nosotros" component={Nosotros} />
          <IndexRoute component={App}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppStart />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm very confused, I've been learning about props and states, but I have not been successful.